# Slow HTTP Responses from Ionic App on iOS 9

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having an issue with Ionic when emulating using iOS version 9.1.  After 2 or 3 minutes my HTTP GET requests slow down from around 20 milliseconds per request to around 60 or 90 seconds per request. My server responds normally when I test it with Fiddler, so it looks like the issue is with iOS.  I'm not seeing any errors in the iOS logs, the HTTP responses are just extremely slow.

```
function search(query) {
          var d = $q.defer();
          $http.get('http://www.myapp.com/api/cars').then(function (res) {
            d.resolve(res.data);
          }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            d.reject();
          });
          return d.promise;
        }
```

Comment: If you remove Ionic and even Angular from the picture and just do a simple XHR with no framework, can you recreate it in that situation?

Comment: No.  If I use Fiddler or Postman and make HTTP requests against my API the requests resolve normally.  This only occurs with Ionic/iOS.

Comment: That's not quite what I asked though. You used something outside the browser. If you use XHR to hit the API in Mobile Safari, can you recreate it?